# Javascript set Dropdown value on Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I creating user script/addon to fill input of google forms but I can't change value for the dropdown.

[demo page](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScl1y5ENRe4F-ox5575664qVqbpE4OVvYfnXPhCRWiFO8b6YA/viewform) and what I have tried

```
document.querySelector('.quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.exportOption').click()
document.querySelectorAll('.quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent.exportContent')[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, so there are 4 element of `.quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent.exportContent` so I need to select last element

```
document.querySelectorAll('.quantumWizMenuPaperselectContent.exportContent')[3].click()
```

or change the selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('.exportSelectPopup div span')[1].click()
```